# CSS not loading in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

**Situation:**

I'm creating a web application using Laravel, but for the moment CSS that i created aren't loading.

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Laravel Version**

*Laravel Framework version 5.2.36*

**master.blade.php code**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>@yield('title')</title>
      <link rel ="stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::secure('src/css/main.css') }}">
    @yield('styles')
  </head>
<body>
  @include('includes.header')
<div class="main">
    @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is there a `src` folder in your `public` folder?

Comment: Is it loading with `asset` like so `<link rel ="stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('src/css/main.css') }}">`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

```
<link rel ="stylesheet" href= "{{ asset('src/css/main.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/') }}./src/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
```